# Get files sorted without extension in batch

Tags: batch-file, dir, extension

I would like to have an option to get all the files in the folder, just the names (no path and no extension) and sorted by name, in a simple batch file.

I know how to get all the names, but it's not sorted:

```
for %%i in (*.mxf) do @echo %%~ni >> names.txt
```

And I know how to get the names sorted, but it comes with the extension:

```
dir /b /o:n >> names.txt
```

How can I combine the two commands? Only the names and sorted.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pipe the output to the [sort](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sort) command:

`(for %%i in (*.mxf) do @echo %%~ni) | sort /o names.txt`

On my system, the files were already sorted by default, so I tested it by reversing the order using the sort option `/r`.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the `dir` command with applicable sorting options in a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop and redirect the output from there to a file giving you the expected result—this is a way to combine the two as requested.

### Script Example

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /o:n "*.mxf"') do @echo %%~ni >> names.txt
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Answer (score 1):

I use this to output a directory list including subdirectories, the saves the output into a text file

```
forfiles /m *.* /s |sort >> FileList2.txt
```